# how did they get equilibrium points from this answer?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

could someone please show me how they got these equilibrium points? not sure if its just simple algebra or you have to do a derivative...how did they get equilibrium points from this answer?

[image]

definition (1) --> equalibrium point for a two-dimentional system is an $(x,y)$ point, where $\dfrac{dx}{dt}=0$ and $\dfrac{dy}{dt}=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting the derivative to zero, you obtain 2 new algebraic equations.

First equation gives $$x = 1-y$$
second equation gives $$x^2+y^2 = 1 \Longrightarrow (1-y)^2 + y^2 = 1$$
Simplify and solve the second equation (2 solutions). Substitute the solutions for $y$ back in the first to find corresponding $x$.

I find the solutions quite clear, I just did it the other way around for the substitution.